# Why do I get a syntax error when creating a PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a function in PostgreSQL using this query:

```sql
create function cs.has_double_bridge(cs.nose_bridge_type) returns boolean as $$
  return $1 = 'double bridge';
$$ language plpgsql stable;
```

But I keep getting an error on the second line:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "return"
LINE 2:   return $1 = 'keyhole';
          ^
```

I am not an expert in PostgreSQL, so I haven't been able to figure out the cause of the error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) PL/pgSQL requires a `BEGIN ... END` block:

```
create function cs.has_double_bridge(cs.nose_bridge_type) 
  returns boolean 
as $$
begin
  return $1 = 'double bridge';
end;
$$ language plpgsql stable;
```

Alternatively you can use a SQL function instead:

```
create function cs.has_double_bridge(cs.nose_bridge_type) 
  returns boolean 
as $$
  select $1 = 'double bridge';
$$ language sql stable;
```

Comment: Ah! I had it wrapped in begin/end but I think perhaps I had them indented... I'm not sure if that matters or not, so maybe I had another mistake.

Comment: Nope, the indentation does not matter.